# Parse - afterSave and access inner field?

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to send some of the data in my request to another client as a push notification.
My request object should be a "Comment" object which has a pointer to a "User" object named "from".

I tried both

```
request.object.get("from").objectId
```

and

```
request.object.get("from").get("objectId");
```

When I log them in console it looks like they are both `undefined`

**EDIT:**

Also tried to use `id` instead of `objectId` in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
request.object.get("from").id
```

but it only works in `beforeSave`. Not quite sure why.